# If Statement in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

How do I add a general "if" statement to my line of code that takes the mean of values >30 in column 'g' for values that appear in column 'n', where column 'n' has values 1 through 5. For a better understanding of the answer you provide, explain your answer as best as you can.

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sept='/t',names = ["n", "p","r","g","h","j"])
df1=df.groupby('n').max()
df2=df1.loc[3:,'j']
df3=df1.groupby('n').mean() 
print(df3)
print(df2)
```

Comment: For a better understanding of your question, explain your question as best as you can. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: I added additional information for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.g[df.g > 30].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me greatly.

Comment: ) I have column 'g' grouped into their respective 'n' values of n= 1 through 5. How would I go about getting the mean of 'g' values >30 for each group that I have created?